# SQL sum up count group by

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Currently have a query that hits AWS Redshift. I have this group by a recipient in order to count the total of the output.

```
select count(CASE WHEN event_name = 'c' THEN 1 END) 
from oe
where owner_id = $1
and rid = $2
and cid = $2
and rbid is not null 
group by recipient 
having count(CASE WHEN event_name = 'c' THEN 1 END) > 0
and count(CASE WHEN event_name = 'd' THEN 1 END) > 0
```

The output from that is this

```
5
4
1
1
```

I'd like to be able, to sum up those numbers to produce a final number, as well as count the number of rows. How can I go about achieving this?

Comment: putting whole query into sum will sum up all the resulting numbers and output  the final summed number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the desired result.

```
select sum(sum_c), count(*) from (
 select count(CASE WHEN event_name = 'c' THEN 1 END) sum_c
from oe
where owner_id = $1
and rid = $2
and cid = $2
and rbid is not null 
group by recipient 
having count(CASE WHEN event_name = 'c' THEN 1 END) > 0
and count(CASE WHEN event_name = 'd' THEN 1 END) > 0) x;
```